# Сomments / Комментарии в YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, комментарии

Получаю комментарии с YouTube по ID видео, для дублирования на нашем сайте.

Сначала все работало хорошо, однако теперь данные также выдаются, но поле комментария (`textDispaly`) пустое.

Пример запроса:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet,replies&videoId=[id]&key=[key]
```

Пример ответа:

```
 {
   "kind": "youtube#commentThread",
   "etag": "\"DsOZ7qVJA4mxdTxZeNzis6uE6ck/tXrnUX6iH_pzsXrM8iQf-TJZYSg\"",
   "id": "z12fibua1ticixwfy22nsfsgclelhzjlx",
   "snippet": {
    "videoId": "9bZkp7q19f0",
    "topLevelComment": {
     "kind": "youtube#comment",
     "etag": "\"DsOZ7qVJA4mxdTxZeNzis6uE6ck/JHggt69t_qgOkY5meyOUgJLi8Ns\"",
     "id": "z12fibua1ticixwfy22nsfsgclelhzjlx",
     "snippet": {
      "authorDisplayName": "TheCramp_8",
      "authorProfileImageUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-tyxGfaVCiHA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACg/Y-P1y_J7g3s/photo.jpg?sz=50",
      "authorChannelUrl": "http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIue6C5vj5uzlW7sOgrnrNQ",
      "authorChannelId": {
       "value": "UCIue6C5vj5uzlW7sOgrnrNQ"
      },
      "videoId": "9bZkp7q19f0",
      "textDisplay": "",
      "authorGoogleplusProfileUrl": "https://plus.google.com/100343550752362869286",
      "canRate": false,
      "viewerRating": "none",
      "likeCount": 1,
      "publishedAt": "2016-02-05T20:00:04.157Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-02-05T20:00:04.157Z"
     }
    },
    "canReply": false,
    "totalReplyCount": 0,
    "isPublic": true
   }
  },
```

С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, это [известный баг](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7969). Он проявляется время от времени при использовании [textFormat](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) = html. Для textFormat = plainText всё должно быть в порядке.